# Inheritance of class relation tree in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, composition

We are developing a game that has multiple game modes in it. We have the following code here:

```cs
// The following will be in our company's code base.

public class GameMode
{
    public GameState currentState;

    public List<GamePlayer> players;
}

public class GameState
{
    public GameMode gameMode;
}

public class GamePlayer
{
    public GameMode gameMode;
}

// The following will be in our game's code base.

public class Deathmatch : GameMode
{
    // Here, we've got a currentState of type GameState, NOT DeathmatchState
    // and a list of type of GamePlayer, NOT DeathmatchPlayer
}

public class DeathmatchState : GameState
{
    // GameMode here, not Deathmatch
}

public class DeathmatchPlayer : GamePlayer
{
    // GameMode here, not Deathmatch
}
```

For the code above, we've encountered a problem of having a field of the base type, not the corresponding inherited type. So we went to do this:

```cs
public class GameMode<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameMode : GameMode<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameState : GameState<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGamePlayer : GamePlayer<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
{
    public TGameState currentState;

    public List<TGamePlayer> players;
}

public class GameState<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameMode : GameMode<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameState : GameState<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGamePlayer : GamePlayer<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
{
    public TGameMode gameMode;
}

public class GamePlayer<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameMode : GameMode<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGameState : GameState<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
    where TGamePlayer : GamePlayer<TGameMode, TGameState, TGamePlayer>
{
    public TGameMode gameMode;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public class Deathmatch : GameMode<Deathmatch, DeathmatchState, DeathmatchPlayer>
{
    // Here, we've got the currentState of type TGameState, which is exactly DeathmatchState
    // and a list of TGamePlayer, which is exactly DeathmatchPlayer
}

public class DeathmatchState : GameState<Deathmatch, DeathmatchState, DeathmatchPlayer>
{
    // Deathmatch here
}

public class DeathmatchPlayer : GamePlayer<Deathmatch, DeathmatchState, DeathmatchPlayer>
{
    // Deathmatch here
}
```

While this actually works perfect, but is it the only way to do it? Or is there any other ways to make it less confused to other programmers?

For this method, we're actually using inheritance for one dimension (Game-Deathmatch relationship), and using generic for another dimension (GameMode-GameState-GamePlayer relationship).

Also I'd like to hear about how other languages deal with this kind of situation :-P

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on gamedev.SE. In my experience, inheritance maps quite poorly to games - hard-coding and composition seem to be better in pretty much any scenario. And I've done my share of horribly object-oriented attempts-at-a-game-engine :D

Comment: [Favour composition over inheritence](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose). Instead of having `GameMode` in your player, inject `IGameMode` into player.

Comment: Do all three classes need to have all three type parameters? GameState and  GamePlayer classes seem to only need TGameMode. GameMode itself needs TGameState and TGamePlayer